# Is there way to view two applications split screen on Android tablets?

Tags: applications, multitasking

Is there way to use two applications simultaneously on split screen on Android tablets? It would be great to put tablet to vertical position open navigation software to upper part of screen and music player to lower and use it at car. Just like [the Kyocera Echo can](http://www.engadget.com/2011/02/07/sprints-kyocera-echo-dual-screen-android-phone-announced-we-go/).

Comment: Is there a Custom Android MOD like CyanoGen supporting this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a company that is working on doing this but they said they will not be releasing it to consumers, they want to go directly to OEMs: [Onskreen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezvAs759rbg).